# at the last line I am getting the error "unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python, machine-learning

In the last line I am getting the error "unexpected EOF while parsing". I know this means I have reached the end with out executing all of the code but I am unsure of where the mistake is. The code was complete, but at the end I wanted to try and use graphviz for the visualization

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn. datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

#load data
wine = load_wine()
X = wine.data
y = wine.target

#split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.02, random_state=42)

#Visulaize data
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

#Train Model
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Executive model
print(model.score(X_test, y_test))

#Visualize model
print(model.feature_importances_)
print (wine.feature_names)

#Plot the tree
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
plot_tree(model.estimators_[0], filled=True, rounded=True, class_names=wine.target_names, feature_names=wine.feature_names)
plt.show()

from IPython.display import Image  
from six import StringIO
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus, graphviz
dot_data = StringIO()  
#Export as dot file
export_graphviz(model.estimators_[0], out_file=dot_data, 
filled=True, rounded=True,
            feature_names=wine.feature_names, 
            class_names=wine.target_names)
#Display in jupyter notebook
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png()
```

Comment: `Image(graph.create_png()` missing closing bracket!

Comment: sheesh I don't know how I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
Image(graph.create_png()
```

You wanted

```
Image(graph.create_png())
```